# Javascript modification at the browser Interface

Tags: php, javascript, curl

Is it possible to modify javascript source code on a https connection before it gets executed by the browser. This modification doesn't have to necessarily come from a man-in-the middle. It can also come from the intended recipient of the script. Also, is there a particular type of request that cannot be made to a PHP server using cURL? In other words, what are the limitations of cURL?

Comment: I am asking this question because i intend to hide something in a javascript variable and to do this, I enclosed the whole code inside an anonymous function. I fear that the intended recipient might try to changed the anonymous function to a named one before code execution so that when the code executes, the variable that holds the secret can be accessed via the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have secrets to hide, don't include them in your Javascript.

Yes, it's quite possible.  With something like Greasemonkey, or a browser plug-in, the user could certainly transform the source before executing it.

Moreover, since your source is eventually delivered in plain text, even if obfuscated, the user can reverse engineer it to find the secret, and often can do so quite quickly.